# How to retrieve data from a Query instead of from Tables with Jackcess

Tags: java, ms-access, jackcess

I have an Access DB, to make the job easier, I did the queries into DB. How I can take data from the query instead of from tables?

To take data from tables I used this code:

```
Table table = db.getTable("matchTable");
Cursor cursor = CursorBuilder.createCursor(table);

while (cursor.findNextRow(Collections.singletonMap("idMatch", 15))) {
       Row row = cursor.getCurrentRow();
       ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Jackcess FAQ (specifically, [here](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/faq.html#query)):

> Can Jackcess execute SQL queries?
>
> As of the 1.1.19 release, Jackcess has the ability to *read* the Queries saved in an Access database (i.e. interpret the data stored in the system Queries table). However, Jackcess does not have the ability to *execute* these Queries.

It means that Jackcess can retrieve the SQL code associated with a saved query in Access, but Jackcess cannot *execute* that SQL code (or return its results).

In other words, if we have a saved query in Access named [MySavedQuery] then Jackcess can retrieve a `String` that contains the SQL command, e.g.,

```sql
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City='wherever'
```

but Jackcess cannot execute that command to actually return the results of that query. Also, the Jackcess method `db.getTable()` can open an Access *table*, but it cannot open a saved query as if it was a table.

However, [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) can execute saved Access queries and return their results. That is, UCanAccess *can* do

```sql
SELECT * FROM MySavedQuery
```

Comment: So in my case I can because the query is in the Access DB, but how i should do?

Comment: @Shiroga I have updated my answer to try and make it more clear: Jackcess cannot return the *results* of an Access saved query.

Comment: UCanAccess is for Linux too?